# Is browser extensions' Storage API data stored UTF-8 encoded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, utf-8, compression, firefox-addon-webextensions

My currently "best understanding" is that Javascript Strings, while in memory are represented as [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString), which means that the the unicode Glyph `a` (Latin Small Letter A) is represented by 2 bytes (in memory) using `UTF-16` text encoding.

This encoding is as maintained when using the Browser's Storage API [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), where the documentation also states that what is stored is a `DOMString`, meaning contrary to popular myth one can usually store `10MB` and not incorrectly `5MB` in localStorage.

My question however is not with regard to `window.localStorage`, but instead with the **web extensions** Storage API [browser.storage.local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage). With `chromium` I was able to test (using [getBytesInUse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/getBytesInUse)) that the data stored was encoded using UTF-8, but I did not find any documentation/specification yet, which states what I up to know have only found out by experiment.

An answer to this question should tell if:

the browser extensions' Storage API data is stored UTF-8 encoded?

and provide a reference that specifies this to be that way.

**Background / Rationale**
I develop a browser extension, who stores text data, which I seek to compress before storage, to conserve space. Since the Storage API provided does not allow storing of raw binary data, I seek to tweak the compression algorithm to be least wasteful, making it counter-productive to base64 convert the binary data. To efficiently store information wihtin text, however it makes a huge difference which text-encoding is used.

The data stored in the browser extension is mostly compressed HTML markup, in English language, which would benefit most from the data storage using `UTF-8` text encoding.

For reference I have checked/read through the following information regarding `String` types related to Browser's Javascript-engine and DOM-engine: [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString), [USVString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString)`

Comment: No, the internal low-level encoding in Chrome is maintained by LevelDB which automatically switches between UTF16, ASCII, and some simple compression. Firefox uses different heuristics. Practically you can use LZString (or LZStringUnsafe which is faster) and its UTF16 methods. You can also use more advanced compressors and store their binary output in IndexedDB.